# How to run the samples given in Spring Projects at Github

Tags: spring, spring-security, maven-2

I came across these links in github. [Spring Projects/spring-security/samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples)

I built these using maven commands `mvn clean install` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. But when I import them in Spring Tool Suite or Eclipse, they just don't run.

Secondly and more importantly, it is always suggested to build using `./gradlew`. Not all developers use Linux. So `./gradlew` is not a viable option most often. Is there any option for windows OS?

Please give some hint of the procedure to run these samples. Why do the developers call them samples if they can't be run and understood for their functionality?

It is my first post ever so please pardon any mistake if it comes by.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse open `HelloWorldApplication.java`. Right click in the file and select `run as java application`.

Comment: There is no class with main method Sir. Had it been such a useless question, I would have never asked on this forum. Please have a look at the samples.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/helloworld/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/HelloWorldApplication.java has a main method.